# SearchView in SherlockListFragment

Tags: tabs, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, searchview

I have some troubles using SearchView in my SherlockListFragment.There is a custom ArrayAdapter and a listview which contains one image and two TextViews for each item. Everything works well until I applied SearchView for my ListFragment. The search icon is expandable and I'm also able to enter words into the search bar.

**PROBLEM**

The custom adapter is able to filter the listview now, but when I delete the last letter from the expandable searchview, or close the searchview, the app crashed.

I have attached my ArrayAdapter class, as well as, my SherlockListFragment below.

**Custom ArrayAdapter with Filter Class**

```
 public static class ShopListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShopEntry>
 {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private List<ShopEntry> filteredData;
    private List<ShopEntry> originalData;

    public ShopListAdapter(Context context, List<ShopEntry> filteredData)
    {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, filteredData);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.filteredData = filteredData;

    }

    public void setData(List<ShopEntry> data)
    {
        clear();
        if(data != null)
        {
            for(ShopEntry ShopEntry : data)
            {
                add(ShopEntry);

            }
        }
        filteredData = data;
        originalData = data;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ShopEntry getItem(int pos)
    {
        return filteredData.get(pos);
    }

    /**
     * Populate new items in the list.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.specific_shop_list_item,
                    parent, false);
        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ShopEntry item = filteredData.get(position);
        String url = item.getImg();
        ((SmartImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.shopImg)).setImageUrl(url);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shopType)).setText(item
                .getShopName());
        view.setBackgroundColor(0xff1e8e8);

        return view;
    }

    private class MyFilter extends Filter
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked" )
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results)
        {
            if(results != null && results.count > 0)
            {
                filteredData = (ArrayList<ShopEntry>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            constraint = constraint.toString();
            filteredData = originalData;
            if(constraint.length() == 0 || constraint.equals(""))
            {
                FilterResults original = new FilterResults();
                original.count = filteredData.size();
                original.values = filteredData;
                return original;
            }
            else
            {
                List<ShopEntry> filtered = new ArrayList<ShopEntry>();
                for(ShopEntry l : filteredData)
                {
                    if(l.getShopName().contains(constraint))
                    { // YOU NEED TO CHANGE THIS
                        filtered.add(l);
                        Log.d("filter", "filter " + constraint + " "
                                + l.getShopName().toString());
                    }
                }
                FilterResults newFilterResults = new FilterResults();
                newFilterResults.count = filtered.size();
                newFilterResults.values = filtered;
                return newFilterResults;
            }
        }
    }

    MyFilter mFilter;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if(mFilter == null)
        {
            mFilter = new MyFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

}
```

**My ListFragment Class**

```
public class ShopListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<ShopEntry>>, OnQueryTextListener
 {

List<ShopEntry> shopEntry = new ArrayList<ShopEntry>();

// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
ShopListAdapter mAdapter;
SearchView searchView;
// If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
String mCurFilter = "";

OnQueryTextListenerCompat mOnQueryTextListenerCompat;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Give some text to display if there is no data. In a real
    // application this would come from a resource.
    setEmptyText("No Such Shop");

    // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
    mAdapter = new ShopListAdapter(getActivity(), shopEntry);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Start out with a progress indicator.
    setListShown(false);

    // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    // Place an action bar item for searching.
    // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_with_search, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    searchView = new SearchView(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar()
            .getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    {
        item.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)
            {
                searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
                searchView.setQuery(null, true);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onClose()
            {
                searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
                searchView.setQuery(null, true);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    item.setActionView(searchView);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
{ // called when the action bar search text has changed. Update
    // the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
    // with this filter.
    String newFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
    // Don't do anything if the filter hasn't actually changed.
    // Prevents restarting the loader when restoring state.
    if(mCurFilter == null && newFilter == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(mCurFilter != null && mCurFilter.equals(newFilter))
    {
        return true;
    }
    mCurFilter = newFilter;
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(mCurFilter.toString());

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public Loader<List<ShopEntry>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
    // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created. This
    // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.

    return new ShopListLoader(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<ShopEntry>> loader,
        List<ShopEntry> data)
{
    // Set the new data in the adapter.
    mAdapter.setData(data);

    // The list should now be shown.
    if(isResumed())
    {
        setListShown(true);
    }
    else
    {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<ShopEntry>> loader)
{
    // Clear the data in the adapter.
    mAdapter.setData(null);
}
 }
```

**Log File**

```
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:212)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:94)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:49)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:155)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:356)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5385)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5204)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:716)
    08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:121)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-20 01:44:44.549: E/AndroidRuntime(4246):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me ? thx

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18245191/557179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `SearchView` in Sherlock is expanded it sets the `TextView` component to `""`, you can see it from the source:

```
 @Override
public void onActionViewExpanded() {
    if (mExpandedInActionView) return;

    mExpandedInActionView = true;
    mCollapsedImeOptions = mQueryTextView.getImeOptions();
    mQueryTextView.setImeOptions(mCollapsedImeOptions | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN);
    mQueryTextView.setText("");
    setIconified(false);
}
```

That's why your filter returns the original data. Contrary, comparing to the `android.widget.SearchView` it does not set the query to "" when the action view is also collapsed. Long story short you need to omit filtering with "" (unless needed), and also check if you are invalidating the `ListView` when the filtering is performed, since you havent posted the filtering implementation.

Edit: Example of filtering listview

private class MyFilter extends Filter {

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    if (results!=null && results.count > 0) {
        items = (ArrayList<Data>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
    items = mOriginalData;
    if (constraint.length() == 0 || constraint.equals("")) {
        FilterResults original = new FilterResults();
        original.count = items.size();
        original.values = items;
        return original;
    } else {
        List<Data> filtered = new ArrayList<Data>();
        for (Data l : items) {
            if ( SOME CONDITION TO FILTER ){ // YOU NEED TO CHANGE THIS
             filtered.add(l);
            }
        }
        FilterResults newFilterResults = new FilterResults();
        newFilterResults.count = filtered.size();
        newFilterResults.values = filtered;
        return newFilterResults;
    }
}
```

};

In your adapter:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new MyFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please take look at the edited version. This time round, it doesn't return me the original list, instead, it displays "No shop" even though I keyed in something match the text in the list. One more strange thing is, I found out only when I key in the package name, it won't show me "No Shop", but the list will remain the same. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh, you mean I can't just use mAdapter.getFilter in onQueryTextChange?   could you provide some examples or give me some hints of how to filter items in adapter based on the ShopListAdapter method that I provided above?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I just uploaded my full java code. So Where should I put private class MyFilter extends Filter ? In my case what should I replace "items" with ? thank you

Comment: If you want to keep the class private put it in same class file with the adapter.

Comment: So both private class myFilter and Filter class have to be put in my adapter class issit?  And "items" refers to List<ShopEntry>, am I right?  And how should I call the Filter class inside my onQueryTextChange() ?  Thank you.

Comment: Same as you do now :)

Comment: Hi, Nikola, I really appreciate your help. I've updated my ShopListAdapter. But now it seems my list can't be filtered again, it just displays the original list. My guess is the way I declare List<ShopEntry> mOriginal; is incorrect, and l.getShopName().contains(constraint) doesn't really make sense, either. Lastly, I got NullPointerException.I really have no idea how to implement this. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Nikola, I modified my code just now. And from the log file, I found out that in my if(l.getShopName().contains(constraint)), the value of l is my package name + an unknown number. I guess it is the memory address, and that's y my listview items can't be filtered. Any solution for this ? thank you very much!

Comment: I've updated my Log File, as well. Log.d("filter", "f "+ constraint + " "+l.getShopName + " "+ filtered);

Comment: I can see Filter class is actually working now through Log File, but my list is still not updated.

Comment: Hi Nikola, now my adapter is able to filter the list, but I encountered NullPointerException.. Take a look at the latest code please..Thank you