# SearchView is empty when calling invalidateOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, searchview

I'm using SearchView (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) to filter items in my listview. I have a listview which includes items with a checkbox (the checkbox is a marker to select the item). When i click the checkbox, i call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. Then there appears a new menu item which can do some things with the "selected" items. Here some Code:

SearchView in menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_movie_icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    hmkcode:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    hmkcode:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
```

Fragment:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu p_Menu, MenuInflater p_Inflater) {
    p_Menu.clear();
    p_Inflater.inflate(R.menu.movie_actionbar, p_Menu);

    m_SearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(p_Menu.findItem(R.id.search_movie_icon));
    m_SearchView.setIconified(false);

    m_OnQueryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String p_NewText) {
        m_MovieManager.setFilter(p_NewText);

        // this call will get the new movie list from the moviemanager and update the view
        updateViews();

        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String p_Submit) {
        // do nothing -> this will be called on pressing enter
        return false;
      }
    };

    m_SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(m_OnQueryTextListener);

    //some more unimportant stuff
  }
```

Checkbox in listadapter:

```
l_ViewHolder.m_cbMarked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View p_View) {
    l_Movie.setMarked(((CheckBox) p_View).isChecked());

    // This should update the optionsmenu to see the new menu item
    ((Activity) m_Context).invalidateOptionsMenu();
  }
}
```

My problem is that the call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` removes the string in my searchview.
I know that there were some changes in SearchView:

Before:

```
@Override
public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
    clearFocus();
    updateViewsVisibility(true);
    mQueryTextView.setImeOptions(mCollapsedImeOptions);
    mExpandedInActionView = false;
}
```

Now:

```
@Override
public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
    setQuery("", false);
    clearFocus();
    updateViewsVisibility(true);
    mQueryTextView.setImeOptions(mCollapsedImeOptions);
    mExpandedInActionView = false;
}
```

I tried some workarounds:

- `StateFulSearchView` from [SearchView in ActionBar -- problems with the *Up* button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148761/searchview-in-actionbar-problems-with-the-up-button)
  Here i have some focus and icon problems...
- A callback which removes my OnChangeTextListener before calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and readd it after this call (to avoid the filter actions) -> it didn't work...
- Safe the filter before calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and set the old filter after that call -> then i can clearly see the flicker effect in my listview :(

I can't find a good solution...
Can someone help me? Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Nobody can help me? Any suggestions?

Comment: ,did you found any solution?

Comment: No but i freezed/cancelled this project. It was my first bigger android project. Currently i'm developing the version "2.0". There are minor changes. I don't have an optionsmenu which i have to update to set visibilities or something like that. I think it was just a design problem.