# ListView Just-In-Time Response to EditText Input

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm writing a dictionary in Android which gets input from an editText and shows the result of the search in the database on a listView. The database includes a set of words and definitions. Here's a part of code I've written:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {    
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      String query = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      showResults(query);
  }
```

and here's the showResults method which must show the search results on the listView:

```
private void showResults(String query) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, new String[] {query}, null);

    String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD, DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word, R.id.definition };

    SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.result, cursor, from, to, RESULT_OK);

    mListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter)words);
}
```

but when I enter input in the editText, I don't see any result dynamically listed.

Comment: See part of my answer that is related to the filtering of listview here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18289135/557179

Get all items in database, then use filter to avoid requering the database over and over, thats expensive. :)

Comment: The third parameter should be the actual selection clause where the `new String[] {query}` will be inserted and not just null, as with null you'll simply get all the results.